# How to create a session array ( need syntax)

Tags: c#

I have created a web application in asp.net(C#) and used static class file to get the check box names in different web forms(pages)The check boxes are dependent of each other and are visible only when some or other check box is checked or unchecked. Now that application is used by multiple users and all checks made by the users  are entering into the static class file .Due to this  application is not showing required check boxes.

is it possible to change the class file to session variables. i have 300 check boxes. so i want to put all the  clicked check boxes into an session variable.

```
public static string[] CheckboxID = new string[350];
```

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding what a static variable does.  A static variable is instantiated once for the entire application regardless of session. So long as your application is on that static variable will be shared among users, sessions you name it. You can read up on it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable#Static_Variables_as_Class_Variables).  In your case you should not use a static field like you're doing there.  Instead just make a property to return the value from the session and methods to add and remove items to it (you can make them static for ease of use but do not store the variables statically).

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string[] CheckBoxes
    {
        get
        {
            string [] result = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckBoxId"] as string[];

            if (result == null)
            {
                result = new string[] { };
            }

            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckBoxId"] = value;
        }
    }

    public static void AddCheckBox(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return;
        }

        var checkboxes = CheckBoxes.ToList();
        checkboxes.Add(value);

        CheckBoxes = checkboxes.Distinct().ToArray();
    }

    public static void RemoveCheckBox(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return;
        }

        var checkboxes = CheckBoxes.ToList();
        checkboxes.RemoveAll(v => v == value);

        CheckBoxes = checkboxes.Distinct().ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Helper.AddCheckBox("This is a Test");

string[] checkboxId = Helper.CheckBoxes;

Helper.RemoveCheckBox("This is a Test");
```

You're going to have to be careful in your use of this.  Without seeing your code, it sounds like you may have more to refactor than just this.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for the help.  i am new to ASP.net(C#). My application works like this.when application loads, i pull all the names of the check boxes (300) and store it in a class file.                    str += r[0].ToString() + r[1].ToString() + r[2].ToString() + r[3].ToString() + r[4].ToString() + r[5].ToString();
                DatabaseInfo.checkBoxNames[i] = Convert.ToString(r[2]);
                DatabaseInfo.checkBoxValues[i] = Convert.ToInt32(r[3]);